# Insert form fields into database (Bottle, sqlite)

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

There has to be a better way to do this.. I've read the bottle documentation, but it doesn't really help all that much. This works, but it's dirty. Seems like I'm missing something.

```
@route('/client/new', method="POST")
def add_new_client():
    c = db.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO Clients VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

    try:
        r = request.POST

        d = r['LastContact'].split('/') # mm/dd/yyyy
        try: lastcontact = datetime(int(d[2]), int(d[0]), int(d[1]))
        except Exception as e: lastcontact = datetime.now()

        try: taxExempt = r['TaxExempt'] 
        except Exception as e: taxExempt = 0

        c.execute(query, (r['FirstName'], r['LastName'], r['Address1'], r['Address2'], r['City'], r['State'], r['Zip'],
                 r['HomePhone'], r['CellPhone'], r['WorkPhone'], r['Email'], r['ContactMethod'], r['ContactTime'],
                 r['ContactFrequency'], lastcontact, taxExempt, r['TaxID'], r['Notes']))
        db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print "ERROR %s" % e
    redirect('/client/%d' % c.lastrowid)
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things would look much more clean if you would use [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ORM, related article:

- [Bottle – Adding SQLAlchemy to the Todo List Web App](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/23/bottle-adding-sqlalchemy-to-the-todo-list-web-app/)

If you wish to stay with mixing SQL and Python, you can simplify the code by using *named/keyword query placeholders* which would allow you to just pass `r` dictionary into the query:

```
d = r['LastContact'].split('/') # mm/dd/yyyy
try: 
    r['LastContact'] = datetime(int(d[2]), int(d[0]), int(d[1]))
except Exception as e: 
    r['LastContact'] = datetime.now()

if 'TaxExempt' not in r:
    r['TaxExempt'] = 0

query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        Clients 
    VALUES
        (NULL, 
         :FirstName, 
         :LastName, 
         :Address1, 
         :Address2, 
         :City, 
         :State, 
         :Zip, 
         :HomePhone, 
         :CellPhone, 
         :WorkPhone,
         :Email, 
         :ContactMethod, 
         :ContactFrequency, 
         :ContactTime, 
         :LastContact, 
         :TaxExempt, 
         :TaxID, 
         :Notes)
"""
c.execute(query, r)
```

Comment: Didn't know that it had named placeholders. That helps while I figure out how to use sqlalchemy. Alchemy seems much better than sqlite3.  Thanks!